# ADF Custom Search Form

Tags: oracle11g, richfaces, oracle-adf

I'm trying to create a custom search form that updates a table **without using the ADF Query Panel**, since i want to keep the same header layout on the "customer" search form page and the "customer" detailed page. Any advice on how to do this?
(Example using the HR Schema, to search customer and view customer page)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some of the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: Thanks! I have only tried with the Query Panel, and with a simple form. Using a simple Form i can update it, selecting a row on the table, but can't do the other way around: Filtering my customers by the form.

I'm new to ADF, so i'm not capable to provide much info

Comment: Lots of answer on google, like: http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/07/implementing-custom-search-form-in-adf.html Also, look at using the ExecWithParams if you want to build it based on bind vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of answer on google, like [this](http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/07/implementing-custom-search-form-in-adf.html).  Also, look at using the [ExecWithParams](http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2007/05/executewithparams-in-your-oracle-adf.html) if you want to build it based on bind vars